# Microsoft Project Summaries looking strange

Tags: microsoft-project, microsoft-project-2010

I'm having an issue with summary tasks in my project, I have a summary task called "Preparing for Initial interview"

this summary should end, and the milestone should be reached on the 4/2/15 when the initial interview was held.

after I reach that milestone for this Summary (Completing interview questions) I want to jump to the first task in the next summary section "section2"

*This throws an error.*

The problem is this summary I've made is a sub-summary of the pre-mentioned Definition summary

I want this summary to be adjacent to the first summary in the project, not a sub-summary.

currently when I use the "[-]" button next to my first summary it closes the other one, I don't want this to happen, both summaries should be under Simply Hill racing project, they shouldn't be inside eachother.

I want this section2 summary to FOLLOW after the Definition summary

I hope I'm being clear enough, I'll post an imgur of my error:

[image]

it SHOULD look something like this:

http://b2b.cbsimg.net/blogs/trafficlightgantt2.png

Answer (score 0):

Select task 13 and click the Outdent task button on the Task Ribbon.  It also appears as though you have typed dates in as all of the Autoscheduled tasks are constrained.  I also suggest changing your summary task 1 & 2 to autoscheduled.